# How to cast variable from string to int in MVC .ASP NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this variable in MVC .ASP NET Razor Synthax:

```
    var data = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["data"];
```

var data is a string. Is there any way i can type cast it into int?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for:

```
var intData = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["data"]);
```

But you definatly should read about [**MVC model binding**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/710776/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-An-Absol). And **name conversations** and **ViewModels** and **Strongly Typed Views**.

When you understand how it work you won't need this convertions anymore.

Answer (score 2):

In razor, you can use @{ //c# code } syntax.. Try this;

```
@{

int value; 
if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["data"], out value)) 
    { 
    // it's a number use the variable 'value' 
    } else { 
    // not a number
     }
}
```